# logging with uwsgi (multiprocess) + flask

Tags: python, logging, uwsgi

I plan to run uwsgi (4 processes) with the following command

```
command = uwsgi
--master --processes 4 --die-on-term
--socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock --file run.py
--callable app --stats /tmp/stats.socket --memory-report --post-buffering  32768
--virtualenv <virtualenv> --logto2 <log_path>
```

I want to use StreamLogger to log to stdout and stderr.
Now my question is: Does uwsgi multiplex log from all 4 worker processes into the log file?

I know probably syslog is a better option and there are many other options:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Logging.html

But I want to start off with the stream logger if it can handle concurrent log messages from all the workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add --log-master and every logline will be serialized to the master that will effectively write the line synchronously to the file.